# Read fields from text file and store them in a structure

Tags: regex, matlab, text-parsing

I am trying to read a file that looks as follows:

```
Data Sampling Rate: 256 Hz
*************************

Channels in EDF Files:
**********************
Channel 1: FP1-F7
Channel 2: F7-T7
Channel 3: T7-P7
Channel 4: P7-O1

File Name: chb01_02.edf

File Start Time: 12:42:57

File End Time: 13:42:57 

Number of Seizures in File: 0

File Name: chb01_03.edf

File Start Time: 13:43:04

File End Time: 14:43:04

Number of Seizures in File: 1

Seizure Start Time: 2996 seconds

Seizure End Time: 3036 seconds
```

So far I have this code:

```
fid1= fopen('chb01-summary.txt')
data=struct('id',{},'stime',{},'etime',{},'seizenum',{},'sseize',{},'eseize',{});
if fid1 ==-1
    error('File cannot be opened ')
end
tline= fgetl(fid1);
while ischar(tline)
    i=1;
    disp(tline);
end
```

I want to use `regexp` to find the expressions and so I did:

```
line1 = '(.*\d{2} (\.edf)' 
data{1} = regexp(tline, line1);
tline=fgetl(fid1);
time = '^Time: .*\d{2]}: \d{2} :\d{2}' ;
data{2}= regexp(tline,time);
tline=getl(fid1);
seizure = '^File: .*\d';
data{4}= regexp(tline,seizure);
if data{4}>0
    stime = '^Time: .*\d{5}'; 
    tline=getl(fid1);
    data{5}= regexp(tline,seizure);
    tline= getl(fid1);
    data{6}= regexp(tline,seizure);
end
```

I tried using a loop to find the line at which file name starts with:

```
for (firstline<1) || (firstline>1 )
    firstline= strfind(tline, 'File Name') 
    tline=fgetl(fid1);
end
```

and now I'm stumped.

Suppose that I am at the line at which the information is there, how do I store the information with `regexp`? I got an empty array for `data` after running the code once...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I find it the easiest to read the lines into a cell array first using [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html):

```
%// Read lines as strings
fid = fopen('input.txt', 'r');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');
fclose(fid);
```

and then apply [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) on it to do the rest of the manipulations:

```
%// Parse field names and values
C = regexp(C{:}, '^\s*([^:]+)\s*:\s*(.+)\s*', 'tokens');
C = [C{:}];                          %// Flatten the cell array
C = reshape([C{:}], 2, []);          %// Reshape into name-value pairs
```

Now you have a cell array `C` of field names and their corresponding (string) values, and all you have to do is plug it into [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) in the correct syntax (using a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) in this case). Note that the field names have spaces in them, so this needs to be taken care of before they can be used (*e.g* replace them with underscores):

```
C(1, :) = strrep(C(1, :), ' ', '_'); %// Replace spaces with underscores
data = struct(C{:});
```

Here's what I get for your input file:

```
data =

            Data_Sampling_Rate: '256 Hz'
                     Channel_1: 'FP1-F7'
                     Channel_2: 'F7-T7'
                     Channel_3: 'T7-P7'
                     Channel_4: 'P7-O1'
                     File_Name: 'chb01_03.edf'
               File_Start_Time: '13:43:04'
                 File_End_Time: '14:43:04'
    Number_of_Seizures_in_File: '1'
            Seizure_Start_Time: '2996 seconds'
              Seizure_End_Time: '3036 seconds'
```

Of course, it is possible to prettify it even more by converting all relevant numbers to numerical values, grouping the 'channel' fields together and such, but I'll leave this to you. Good luck!