# Parse a PC-Axis (.px) file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text-parsing

**Background**: PC-Axis is a file format format used for dissemination of statistical information. The format is used by a number of national statistical organisations to disseminate official statistics.

A PC-Axis file looks a little like this, although they're usually a lot longer:

```
CHARSET=”ANSI”;
MATRIX="BE001";
SUBJECT-CODE="BE";
SUBJECT-AREA="Population";
TITLE="Population by region, time, marital status and sex.";
Data=
".." ".." ".." ".." ".." 
".." ".." ".." ".." ".." 
".." 24.80 34.20 52.00 23.00 
".." 32.10 40.30 50.70 1.00 
".." 31.60 35.00 49.10 2.30 
41.20 43.00 50.80 60.10 0.00 
50.90 52.00 53.90 65.90 0.00 
28.90 31.80 39.60 51.00 0.00;
```

More details about PC-Axis files can be found at the [Statistics Sweden website](http://www.scb.se/Pages/List____314011.aspx), but the basic gist is that the metadata is positioned at the top of the file and after "DATA=" is the actual data itself. It's also worth noting that the data is organized more like a data-table rather than in columns.

**The Problem**: I'd like to parse a PC-Axis file using Matlab, but I'm a little stumped as to how to go about doing it. Does anyone know how to parse one of these files in Matlab? Would it be easier to parse this type of file using some other language, like Perl, and then import the data into Matlab, or, would Matlab be a suitable enough tool for the job? Note that the plan would be to analyze the data in Matlab after the text processing stage.

I've tried using Matlab's text processing tools such as fgetl, textscan, fscanf, and a few others, but it's terribly tricky. Does anyone have any pointers on how to go about doing it?

Essentially, I'd like to store each of the keywords (CHARSET, MATRIX, etc.) and their corresponding values (ANSI, BE001, etc.) as metadata in Matlab - as a structure, perhaps. I'd like to have the data stored in Matlab also - as a matrix, for example.

**Note**: I'm aware of the [pxR package (CRAN)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pxR/index.html) in R, which works a treat for reading .px files into the workspace as a data.frame object. There's also a Perl module called [Data::PcAxis (CPAN)](http://search.cpan.org/~fod/Data-PcAxis-0.0.6/) that is also very good, but I'm specifically wanting to know how to parse a .px file using Matlab.

**UPDATE:** I should have mentioned that in addition to *metadata* and *data*, there are also *variables*. This is best explained by an example. The example PC-Axis file below is the same as the one above except I've added two variables. They're named VALUES("Month") and VALUES("region") and are positioned *after* the metadata and *before* the data.

```
CHARSET=”ANSI”;
MATRIX="BE001";
SUBJECT-CODE="BE";
SUBJECT-AREA="Population";
TITLE="Population by region, time, marital status and sex.";
VALUES("Month")="1976M01","1976M02","1976M03","1976M04",
"1976M05","1976M06","1976M07","1976M08",
"1976M09","1976M10","1976M11","1976M12";
VALUES("region")="Sweden","Germany","France",
"Ireland","Finland";
Data=
".." ".." ".." ".." ".." 
".." ".." ".." ".." ".." 
".." 24.80 34.20 52.00 23.00 
".." 32.10 40.30 50.70 1.00 
".." 31.60 35.00 49.10 2.30 
41.20 43.00 50.80 60.10 0.00 
50.90 52.00 53.90 65.90 0.00 
28.90 31.80 39.60 51.00 0.00;
```

Textscan works a treat when reading in each line of the text file as a string (in a cell array). However, the elements after the "=" sign for both of the variables (i.e. VALUES("Month") and VALUES("region")) span more than one line. It seems that using textscan in this case means that some strings would have to be concatenated, say, for example, in order to collect the list of months (1976M01 to 1976M12).

**Question**: What's the best way to collect the variables data? Read the text file as a single string and then use strtok twice to extract the substring of dates? Perhaps, there's a better (more systematic) way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Matlab is sufficient to do what you want. I would give it a go, and then post your specific challenges. For example, try using textscan to parse the matrix (see my answer below). If you run into trouble, post your specific textscan questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually `textscan` and `regexp` is the way to go when parsing string fields (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17818267/1336150#17819161)):

1. Read the input lines as strings with `textscan`:

   ```
   fid = fopen('input.px', 'r');
   C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');
   fclose(fid);
   ```
2. Parse the header field names and values using `regexp`. Picking the right regular expression should do the trick!

   ```
   X = regexp(C{:}, '^\s*([^=\(\)]+)\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"\s*', 'tokens');
   X = [X{:}];                          %// Flatten the cell array
   X = reshape([X{:}], 2, []);          %// Reshape into name-value pairs
   ```
3. The "VALUE" fields may span over multiple lines, so they need to be concatenated first:

   ```
   idx_data = find(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(C{:}, '^\s*Data')), 1);
   idx_values = find(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(C{:}, '^\s*VALUES')));
   Y = arrayfun(@(m, n){[C{:}{m:m + n - 1}]}, ...
      idx_values(idx_values < idx_data), diff([idx_values; idx_data]));
   ```

   ... and then tokenized:

   ```
   Y = regexp(Y, '"([^,"]+)"', 'tokens');  %// Tokenize values
   Y = cellfun(@(x){{x{1}{1}, {[x{2:end}]}}}, Y); %// Group values in one array
   Y = reshape([Y{:}], 2, []);             %// Reshape into name-value pairs
   ```
4. Make sure the field names are legal (I've decided to convert everything to lowercase and replace apostrophes and any whitespace with underscores), and plug them into a struct:

   ```
   X = [X, Y];                             %// Store all fields in one array
   X(1, :) = lower(regexprep(X(1, :), '-+|\s+', '_')); 
   S = struct(X{:});
   ```

Here's what I get for your input file (only the header fields):

```
S =
          charset: 'ANSI'
           matrix: 'BE001'
     subject_code: 'BE'
     subject_area: 'Population'
            title: 'Population by region, time, marital status and sex.'
            month: {1x12 cell}
           region: {1x5 cell}
```

As for the data itself, it needs to be handled separately:

1. Extract data lines after the "Data" field and replace all `".."` values with default values (say, `NaN`):

   ```
   D = strrep(C{:}(idx_data + 1:end), '".."', 'NaN');
   ```

   Obviously this assumes that there are only numerical data after the "Data" field. However, this can be easily modified if this is not case.
2. Convert the data to a numerical matrix and add it to the structure:

   ```
   D = cellfun(@str2num, D, 'UniformOutput', false);
   S.data = vertcat(D{:})
   ```

And here's `S.data` for your input file:

```
S.data =

        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
        NaN   24.80000   34.20000   52.00000   23.00000
        NaN   32.10000   40.30000   50.70000    1.00000
        NaN   31.60000   35.00000   49.10000    2.30000
   41.20000   43.00000   50.80000   60.10000    0.00000
   50.90000   52.00000   53.90000   65.90000    0.00000
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent answer, Eitan T! Thank you very much for your help. I've been able to modify your suggested code to take care of a few other things I didn't mention in my original question. I was wondering if you could offer a second round of help regarding the Update that I made to the question. If you could take a look, that'd be great. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @GraemeWalsh Glad to help. How do you want the "values" field to be interpreted? That is, how should the corresponding field in the resulting structure look like?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, Eitan. Perhaps something like the following. S.month = 1976M01 1976M02 1976M03 1976M04 and so on... such that the output is an n x 1 column vector/matrix. For S.region =, the output could either be an n x 1 and 1 x n vector/matrix.

Comment: Try something to this effect: tmp = textscan('a,b,c,d', '%s', 'delimiter', ','); tmp{:}; You can parse each list (represented in your file as a string) using this same approach.

Comment: @GraemeWalsh I've updated my answer, have a look. The values of each "VALUE" field are grouped in a cell array for your convenience. Note that I've fixed some other minor issues, so make sure you use the entire updated code.

Comment: @EitanT I tried running your code, but I got the following error: `S = struct(X{:});` _Error using struct. Array dimensions of input '12' must match those of input '10', or be scalar._ Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @GraemeWalsh Yeah, I forgot a pair of curly braces in the `Y = cellfun(...)` line when typing. I think it should be working now.

Comment: The code works now. Thanks very much for the help, @EitanT. I wish I could upvote your answer more than once! Great answer and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not personally familiar with PC-Axis files, but here are my thoughts.

Parse the header first. If the header is of fixed size, you can read in that many lines and parse out the values you want. The *regexp* method may be useful for this.

The data appear to be both string and numeric. I would change the ".." values to NaN (make an original backup first, of course), and then scan the matrix using *textscan*. Textscan can be tricky, so make sure the file parses completely. If textscan encounters a line that does not match the format string, it will stop parsing. You can check the position of the file handle (using *ftell*) to see if it matches the end of the file (you can *fseek* to the end of the file to find what that value should be). The length of the cell arrays returned by textscan should all be the same. If not, the length will tell you what line they failed on - you can check this line with a text editor to see what violated the format.

You can assign and access fields in Matlab structs using string arguments. For example:

```
foo.('a') = 1;
foo.a
ans = 
     1
```

So, the workflow I suggest is to parse the header lines, assigning each attribute/value pair as field/value pairs in struct. Then parse the matrix (after some brief text preprocessing to make sure all the data are numeric).

Comment: Great answer, Gordon Bean. Thank you for your help. I would like to ask you if you'd know to go about parsing the "variables" that I mention in the Update that I made to my question. Any advice you can give would be greatly appreciated.